# Fixed effects regression with a loop is not workling

Tags: stata

I do following fixed effects regression with a loop. I always get an error "option if is not allowed"!

```
levelsof Sic, local(Sic)

xtset Year
foreach i of local Sic {

 xtreg y mq r d, fe if Sic == `i'
    eststo
}
```

if i do the same regression with a normal OLS regression, its working without any problems. why?

Answer (score 1):

The if qualifier should come before the comma, options afterwards.

```
levelsof Sic, local(Sic)

foreach i of local Sic {
    eststo: xtreg y mq r d  if Sic == `i', fe
}
```

I assume it worked with OLS because you did not have to specify any options.